# How to Parse student marks .txt data to google sheet using google script

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have multiple .txt file that contains students' mark for each subject.

1. [students' mark1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1p-T-8W3TT-LLOMtwxUHDKEyH3oFDqe5W/view?usp=sharing)
2. [students' mark2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KDoHEF-qRyJlsgAVRsynGwZ8RMaCY8JO/view?usp=sharing)

I want to parse the student mark to google sheet using google script and the output should be like this.

1. Student's mark sheet.

[image: student sheet image]

I have a problem with the range of the column as each student they are taking a different number of subject. Is there any suggestion on the parsing method?

```
sheet.getRange(lastRow +1,5,mark.length,marks[1].length).setValues(mark);
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While including links to sample files might be helpful, questions should be self-contained. Considering this, please add sample file content directly into the question body and a [mcve] (we don't how you declared `lastRow` and the other variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Code Update. If student have max 8 subject. (you can change to 10 or 50)

```
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById('ID').getBlob().getDataAsString();
  const data = Utilities.parseCsv(file,'|');
  const arr = []
  const index = [] //0,7,12
  for(let i =0; i< data.length;i++){
    if(data[i].toString().includes('*')){
      index.push(i);
    }
  }
  const arr1 = []
  for (let i =0;i< index.length;i++){
      const start = index[i];
      const end = index[i+1]
      if(i+1 > index.length){
        arr1.push(data.slice(end))
      }else{
        arr1.push(data.slice(start,end))
      }
  }
  const finalarr = []
  for(let i=0; i< arr1.length;i++){
    const transit = []
    for(let j=0;j<arr1[i].length;j++){
       if(j == 0){
         transit.push(arr1[i][j][0],arr1[i][j][2])
       }else{
         transit.push(arr1[i][j][0].split(':')[1])
       }
    }
    //change the max subject length in here. Replace 8 with your desired numbers
    const arr_new = new Array(8)
    const arr_desired_length = transit.concat(arr_new.slice(transit.length))
    finalarr.push(arr_desired_length)
  }

  finalarr.forEach(r =>{
    if(r[0].includes('*')){
      r[0] = r[0].replace('*','')
    }
  })

  
  //sheet.getRange(lastRow +1,5,finalarr.length,finalarr[0].length).setValues(finalarr);
  console.log(finalarr)
  //OUTPUT in the same length
  [ [ 'ELMI ALSA', '89.0', '60', '88', '78', '68', '89', '70' ],
  [ 'EMMY JOE', '80.0', '86', '84', '89', '90', ,  ],
  [ 'ELIZA MOHRE', '73', '60', '70', , , ,  ] ]
```

Comment: i try to print on the google sheet `//sheet.getRange(lastRow +1,5,finalarr.length,finalarr[1].length).setValues(finalarr);`, but i found exception error where  The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 8 but the range has 6.

Comment: code updated. if student have 10 subject , you can change new Array(8), the number 8 to 10. or with the total subject.  This will solve the issue with different length of array.

Comment: This working for me. Thanks @liquidkat

Answer (score 0):

When I saw your sample image, I guessed that your current issue might be due to the array length of each element in the values for putting to the Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
sheet.getRange(lastRow +1,5,mark.length,marks[1].length).setValues(mark);
```

#### To:

```
const maxLen = Math.max(...mark.map(r => r.length));
const values = mark.map(r => r.length < maxLen ? [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill("")] : r);
sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 5, values.length, values[1].length).setValues(values);
```

- In this modification, each length of your values becomes the same length. By this, `setValues` can be used.

#### Note:

- In your showing script, it seems that `mark` and `marks` are used. From your script, I understood that `mark` is the value for putting to Spreadsheet.

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: this is working also. Thanks @Tanaike

Comment: @lvsilver Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.